# Обработка полученных данных при POST-запросе через Apache HttpComponents

Tags: java, http

Необходимо получить токен через API кастомного сайта. Пытаюсь использовать Apache HttpComponents, вот что примерно получилось:

```
HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://portal.com:8080/api/token/get?variant=4");

//Request parameters and other properties.
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("variant", "4"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));

//Execute and get the response.
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
System.out.println("Responce: " + entity);
System.out.println("Responce: " + response.getStatusLine() + " "+ entity.getContent());

if (entity != null) {
    InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
    try {
        System.out.println("content^ " + instream);
    } finally {
        instream.close();
    }
}
```

Для примера, в postman-е я отправляю POST-запрос на адрес http://portal.com:8080/api/token/get с параметрами variant:4, он формирует такой запрос: http://portal.com:8080/api/token/get?variant=4, и в ответ мне возвращается токен типа *af704d979924402e9509eafd415649c8*.
В Java, я так понимаю, ответ сервера берётся в этой переменной `instream`? Когда я пытаюсь вывести эту переменную, мне пишет "org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@7ea9e1e2", но это явно не то, что мне необходимо.

Comment: Оно вам всё правильно пишет, потому что данные из стрима надо еще прочитать как это сделать можно посмотреть тут: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/inputstream_read.htm

Comment: @GVArt это не хеш, не надо вводить в заблуждение. Это дефолтная реализация метода toString().

Answer (score 0):

Получилось, используя `.string()` вместо `.toString()`.